# Наголос у слові "Великодня"

Tags: наголос

Як правильно поставити  наголос у слові "Великодня"?
Скрізь говорять великОдня.
Але у слові Великдень - наголос на другий склад.

У тлумачному словнику:
ВЕЛИ́КДЕНЬ, кодня, чол., церк. Християнське весняне свято, присвячене воскресінню міфічного засновника християнства — Христа.

Comment: Яке саме слово Ви маєте на увазі: _Великодня_ як прикметник (тобто: (який?) _великодній_, (яка?) _великодня_, (яке?) _великоднє_) чи _Великодня_ як родовий відмінок іменника (тобто: (що?) _Великдень_, (чого?) _Великодня_, (чим?) _Великоднем_)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сайт [Мова- ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/velukden) 
[image]

[Експрес-урок української](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcBSsJak2ow)

***Наголос на другий склад.***

Comment: наші дві відповіді саме покриють обидва можливих питання.

Comment: @P.Vovk саме так

Answer (score 2):

Дуже помічний сайт в таких випадках ["Словники України" on-line](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/):

**відмінок — однина | множина**

- називний — Вели́кдень | Вели́кодні
- родовий — **Вели́кодня**| Вели́коднів
- давальний — Вели́кодню, Вели́кодневі | Вели́кодням
- знахідний — Вели́кдень | Вели́кодні
- орудний — Вели́коднем | Вели́коднями
- місцевий — на/у Вели́кодні, Вели́кодню | на/у Вели́коднях
- кличний — Вели́кодню | Вели́кодні

Отже, наголос на другий склад. Вел**и**кодня.